# installing older version of R on RHEL7 together with latest R version

Tags: linux, r

I specifically need to install a second version of R on my server (running 3.2 installed by yum and uptodate) in order to comply with GenePattern (a Broad Institute bioinformatics platform).
I found the source for required R v2.5.1 at CRAN but building it leads to error.

I now try to build it from source in my own home
I tried:

```
./configure
./configure --enable-R-shlib
./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-x=no
./configure --with-x=no
```

All ended with:

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

although I have the X11 devel installed:

```
rpm -qa|grep libX11
libX11-devel-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64
libX11-devel-1.6.3-2.el7.i686
libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.i686
libX11-common-1.6.3-2.el7.noarch
libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64
```

What can I do to pass this

full configure output:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /usr/bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking for working aclocal... found
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake... found
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking whether perl version is at least 5.004... yes
checking for dvips... /usr/bin/dvips
checking for tex... /usr/bin/tex
checking for latex... /usr/bin/latex
checking for makeindex... /usr/bin/makeindex
checking for pdftex... /usr/bin/pdftex
checking for pdflatex... /usr/bin/pdflatex
checking for makeinfo... /usr/bin/makeinfo
checking whether makeinfo version is at least 4.7... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xpdf... no
checking for gv... no
checking for gnome-gv... no
checking for ggv... no
checking for kghostview... no
checking for open... /usr/bin/open
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
checking whether g++ can compile ObjC++... no
checking whether  can compile ObjC++... no
checking for Objective C++ compiler... no working compiler found
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gfortran PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking readline/history.h usability... no
checking readline/history.h presence... no
checking for readline/history.h... no
checking readline/readline.h usability... no
checking readline/readline.h presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... yes
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for history_truncate_file... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

Comment: You are missing header files.  You need to determine which header files.  You might have to take considerable amount of time by searching each .c file to determine which header files you don't have on your system in the expected location.

Comment: I could finally build after incrementally fix each error with the corresponding exclusion: ''' ./configure --prefix=/opt/genepattern --with-readline=no --enable-R-shlib --with-x=no''' I have no clue what I lost by doing this but at least I have now a R2.5.1 build on the machine. Any info on what I lost is welcome.